# Create type date in django form

Tags: django, forms, date, types

Good morning,

I'm looking for a way to create a type date in django form. But all types are "text" and then the html don't show me what I want. And I want to set a id/class also.

```
date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'field1', 'class': 'something'}))
```

This code creates a type text and it's useless for me. How can I create a type 'date' ?

Thanks a lot.ee

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own widget subclass with that type, and use it in your form:

```
class DateTypeInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

...

date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateTypeInput(...))
```

Note that the date input type is [not well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) across browsers.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. I can't understand why is deprected, there is another new type to replace the deprectaed 'date'?